# How to add a header and footer spacing in a ListView Android?

Tags: android, listview

Please. i want to know how to added a header and footer spacing in a ListView android. The aim goal is to make a header wich on i will put the account information (Name, surname, picture...) like Gmail mobile app in the navigation drawer. These is a screen example https://i.stack.imgur.com/vijBO.jpg

My Navigation Drawer Adapter :

```
 mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new String[] {
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    getString(R.string.title_section5),
                    getString(R.string.title_section6)}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));

            //To Set the icones
            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spots);
            Drawable image2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sessions);

            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( image, null, null, null);


            return textView;
        }
    });
```

NavigationDrawerLayout :

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@color/connexion_button"
android:padding="16dip"
android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.NavigationDrawerFragment"
android:clipToPadding="false"
/>
```

Comment: Are the header and footer to be **always visible** (fixed) or do they have to **scroll** with the ListView Items?

Comment: No. it will be fix !

Comment: So, you can't use the addHeader and addFooter methods. You have to design a layout where you have  (for instance) a header view (anything you want, even a layout) a ListView and a footer view (again, what you want)

Comment: please post the code and xml

Comment: So... solved? Either remove your question or add a **[SOLVED]** tag to the title.

Comment: done, i talk about the code that i have added :p